# How can I work with multiple Java projects in intellij?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Today I was working with multiple Java programs for one project with IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate shown in the following image: [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9vOA.png) The example in the image was not working, so I am not sure what approach to take. "Prueba" means is "test" in Spanish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure multiple projects as modules in IntelliJ IDEA.

See the Project [Structure | Modules](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html) dialog where you can additional modules and configure the [content roots](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-content-roots.html) for them.

Answer (score 3):

When I want to work on multiple things, I create an empty folder. Open the folder, create modules and give it an output path. I think this may be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It's not currently possible to work on the multiple projects in the same IntelliJ Idea window.

Related topic on the intellij-support forum: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206326369-How-to-have-multiple-projects-in-same-window-